# Tensorflow slow performances using tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization

I have implemented a simple trainer class in tensorflow. I am running some experiments to check code performances, but I am having problems understanding what is happening under the hood of **tf.data.Dataset** and **tf.function**.

In the following I am going present the tests that I have ran and in the end there will be some questions about the results that I got.

Configuration: Intel i3 cpu, tensorflow-cpu 2.1

```
class Trainer:
    def __init__(self, model, optimizer, loss):
        self.model = model
        self.loss_function = loss
        self.optimizer = optimizer

    @tf.function
    def train_step(self, inputs, targets):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.model(inputs)
            loss = self.loss_function(targets, predictions)
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_variables))
        return loss

    # fit using dataset
    @tf.function
    def fit0(self, dataset, epochs):
        for epoch in tf.range(epochs):
            for input_batch, target_batch in dataset:
                self.train_step(input_batch, target_batch)

    # fit using list of tensors
    @tf.function
    def fit1(self, inputs, targets, epochs):
        for epoch in tf.range(epochs):
            for input_batch, target_batch in zip(inputs, targets):
                self.train_step(input_batch, target_batch)
```

In the following **train_step** will always be wrapped in **tf.function**.

**fit0**, **fit1** will be tested with and without **tf.function**.

Here the code that I run the tests with:

```
input_size = 10000
batch_size = 100
q = input_size // batch_size

# create random inputs (x) and outputs (y)
x = tf.random.normal((input_size, 1), dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.random.normal((input_size, 1), dtype=tf.float32)

splits = tf.fill([q, ], batch_size)

# create a list of tensors rappresenting batches
x_list = tf.split(x, splits)
y_list = tf.split(y, splits)

# create datasets in the different ways
dataset0 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).batch(batch_size)
dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.stack(x_list), tf.stack(y_list)))

# model definition
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='tanh', input_shape=(1,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')])

# trainer initialization
trainer = Trainer(model=model, optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())

# first run to perform initializations
time0 = time.time()
trainer.fit0(dataset=dataset0, epochs=tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.int32))
time0 = time.time() - time0

time1 = time.time()
trainer.fit0(dataset=dataset1, epochs=tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.int32))
time1 = time.time() - time1

time2 = time.time()
trainer.fit1(inputs=x_list, targets=y_list, epochs=tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.int32))
time2 = time.time() - time2

print("first fit0 with dataset0 took {} seconds".format(time0))
print("first fit0 with dataset1 took {} seconds".format(time1))
print("first fit1 with tensorlist took {} seconds".format(time2))

# measure performances
time0 = time.time()
trainer.fit0(dataset=dataset0, epochs=tf.constant(100, dtype=tf.int32))
time0 = time.time() - time0

time1 = time.time()
trainer.fit0(dataset=dataset1, epochs=tf.constant(100, dtype=tf.int32))
time1 = time.time() - time1

time2 = time.time()
trainer.fit1(inputs=x_list, targets=y_list, epochs=tf.constant(100, dtype=tf.int32))
time2 = time.time() - time2

print("fit0 with dataset0 took {} seconds".format(time0))
print("fit0 with dataset1 took {} seconds".format(time1))
print("fit1 with tensorlist took {} seconds".format(time2))
```

Here the test results:

The first test is with 100 batches of 100 samples each.

> input_size = 10000
>   batch_size = 100
>
> without @tf.function:
>   first fit0 with dataset0 took 0.9953532218933105 seconds
>   first fit0 with dataset1 took 0.07995295524597168 seconds
>   first fit1 with tensorlist took 0.05196571350097656 seconds
>   fit0 with dataset0 took 10.46957802772522 seconds
>   fit0 with dataset1 took 7.822799205780029 seconds
>   fit1 with tensorlist took 4.650130748748779 seconds
>
> with @tf.function:
>   first fit0 with dataset0 took 1.4042332172393799 seconds
>   first fit0 with dataset1 took 0.46071624755859375 seconds
>   first fit1 with tensorlist took 7.3524699211120605 seconds
>   fit0 with dataset0 took 15.077088832855225 seconds
>   fit0 with dataset1 took 9.136569738388062 seconds
>   fit1 with tensorlist took 2.1366817951202393 seconds

The second one is with 1 batch of 100000 samples.

> input_size = 100000
>   batch_size = 100000
>
> without @tf.function:
>   first fit0 with dataset0 took 1.1792669296264648 seconds
>   first fit0 with dataset1 took 0.027983427047729492 seconds
>   first fit1 with tensorlist took 0.020987749099731445 seconds
>   fit0 with dataset0 took 28.71895956993103 seconds
>   fit0 with dataset1 took 2.730872869491577 seconds
>   fit1 with tensorlist took 2.194814682006836 seconds
>
> with @tf.function:
>   first fit0 with dataset0 took 1.5979444980621338 seconds
>   first fit0 with dataset1 took 0.4557182788848877 seconds
>   first fit1 with tensorlist took 0.3708038330078125 seconds
>   fit0 with dataset0 took 36.43854784965515 seconds
>   fit0 with dataset1 took 9.819332122802734 seconds
>   fit1 with tensorlist took 2.1136972904205322 seconds

Questions:

1. Why does **tf.data.Dataset** provide worst performances when wrapped with **tf.function**?
2. Even if dataset0 and dataset1 are functionally equivalent. What are the under-the-hood differences between the two? Why is dataset1 performing better than dataset0?
3. **fit1** with **tf.function** got the best long-run performances.

   - Is it possible to achieve the same performance using **tf.data.Dataset**?
   - Why is it taking so much time for the initialization?
     When using 100 batches the first run took 7.3524699211120605 seconds and this time increase by increasing the number of batches.
     I guess is because autograph is creating a bigger graph, unrolling the computation of the different batches. I do not see any opportunity for parallelization though, because each batch is dependent on the result of the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

I got good performance improvements, code and results are shown below.
However I am only partially able to answer the questions and in particular the second one still remains open.

Configuration: Intel i3 cpu, tensorflow-cpu 2.1
Here is the improved code for function **fit0**, the rest of **Trainer** class is unchanged:

```
# fit using dataset
@tf.function
def fit0(self, dataset, epochs, batches, unroll=1):
    tf.assert_equal(tf.is_tensor(unroll), False, "unroll must be a python variable.")
    tf.assert_equal(tf.math.floormod(batches, unroll), tf.constant(0), "unroll must be a divisor of batches.")

    entries = epochs * batches / unroll
    it = iter(dataset)

    for entry in tf.range(entries):
        # this loop gets unrolled if unroll
        # is python variable, not a tensor.
        for _ in range(unroll):
            input_batch, target_batch = next(it)
            self.train_step(input_batch, target_batch)
```

Here the code that I run the tests with:

```
input_size = 100000
batch_size = 100
num_epochs = 100
num_unroll = 5

num_batches = input_size // batch_size

# create random inputs (x) and outputs (y)
x = tf.random.normal((input_size, 1), dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.random.normal((input_size, 1), dtype=tf.float32)

splits = tf.fill([num_batches, ], batch_size)
x_list, y_list = tf.split(x, splits), tf.split(y, splits)

# create dataset
dataset0 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).batch(batch_size).cache().prefetch(1).repeat(num_epochs)
dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.stack(x_list), tf.stack(y_list))).cache().prefetch(1).repeat(num_epochs)

# model definition
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='tanh', input_shape=(1,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')])

# trainer initialization
trainer = Trainer(model=model, optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())

# first run to perform initializations
time0 = time.perf_counter()
trainer.fit0(
    dataset=dataset0,
    epochs=tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.int32),
    batches=tf.constant(num_batches, dtype=tf.int32),
    unroll=num_unroll)
time0 = time.perf_counter() - time0

time1 = time.perf_counter()
trainer.fit0(
    dataset=dataset1,
    epochs=tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.int32),
    batches=tf.constant(num_batches, dtype=tf.int32),
    unroll=num_unroll)
time1 = time.perf_counter() - time1

time2 = time.perf_counter()
trainer.fit1(inputs=x_list, targets=y_list, epochs=tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.int32))
time2 = time.perf_counter() - time2

print("first fit0 with dataset0 took {} seconds".format(time0))
print("first fit0 with dataset1 took {} seconds".format(time1))
print("first fit1 with tensorlist took {} seconds".format(time2))

# measure performances
time0 = time.perf_counter()
trainer.fit0(
    dataset=dataset0,
    epochs=tf.constant(num_epochs, dtype=tf.int32),
    batches=tf.constant(num_batches, dtype=tf.int32),
    unroll=num_unroll)
time0 = time.perf_counter() - time0

time1 = time.perf_counter()
trainer.fit0(
    dataset=dataset1,
    epochs=tf.constant(num_epochs, dtype=tf.int32),
    batches=tf.constant(num_batches, dtype=tf.int32),
    unroll=num_unroll)
time1 = time.perf_counter() - time1

time2 = time.perf_counter()
trainer.fit1(inputs=x_list, targets=y_list, epochs=tf.constant(num_epochs, dtype=tf.int32))
time2 = time.perf_counter() - time2

print("fit0 with dataset0 took {} seconds".format(time0))
print("fit0 with dataset1 took {} seconds".format(time1))
print("fit1 with tensorlist took {} seconds".format(time2))
```

> 1. Why does **tf.data.Dataset** have worst performances when wrapped with **tf.function**?

I don't know exactly what's going on under the hood, but it can be solved by replacing:

```
dataset0 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).batch(batch_size)
dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.stack(x_list), tf.stack(y_list)))
```

with this new datasets which also include epoches as well as using cache and prefetch.

```
dataset0 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).batch(batch_size).cache().prefetch(1).repeat(num_epochs)
dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.stack(x_list), tf.stack(y_list))).cache().prefetch(1).repeat(num_epochs)
```

Some more information can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance).

I tested **fit0**, **fit1** with and without **tf.function**, but with this changes I always got better performances by using **tf.function**, therefore only the latter will be shown.

The input_size used is 10 times bigger. Here the test results:

The first test is with 1000 batches of 100 samples each.
Notice that num_unroll = 5 improves performances compared to num_unroll = 1. Setting num_unroll > 5 does not provide any further improvements.

> input_size = 100000
>   batch_size = 100
>   num_epochs = 100
>   num_unroll = 5
>
> first fit0 with dataset0 took 2.2224882999999993 seconds
>   first fit0 with dataset1 took 0.804360700000001 seconds
>   first fit1 with tensorlist took 88.2123332 seconds
>   fit0 with dataset0 took 35.27911590000001 seconds
>   fit0 with dataset1 took 20.370243099999982 seconds
>   fit1 with tensorlist took 23.66727979999999 seconds

The second one is with 1 batch of 1000000 samples.

> input_size = 100000
>   batch_size = 100000
>
> input_size = 1000000
>   batch_size = 1000000
>   num_epochs = 100
>   num_unroll = 1
>
> first fit0 with dataset0 took 4.3616363 seconds
>   first fit0 with dataset1 took 0.7977632000000003 seconds
>   first fit1 with tensorlist took 0.7329889000000005 seconds
>   fit0 with dataset0 took 21.131495899999997 seconds
>   fit0 with dataset1 took 19.915148600000002 seconds
>   fit1 with tensorlist took 19.817472700000003 seconds

The above results allow to answer the question:

> 3. **fit1** with **tf.function** got the best long-run performances.
>
>    - Is it possible to achieve the same performance using **tf.data.Dataset**?
>    - Why is it taking so much time for the initialization?
>        When using 100 batches the first run took 7.3524699211120605 seconds and this
>        time increase by increasing the number of batches.   I guess is
>        because autograph is creating a bigger graph, unrolling the
>        computation of the different batches. I do not see any opportunity for
>        parallelization though, because each batch is dependent on the result
>        of the previous one.

By inspecting the structure of the graph on the **TensorBoard** it is easy to see that using autograph on the **fit1** function a very large graph is created by unrolling the loop entirely.
This provides better performance but a very long time for the creation of the graph and most likely an excessive use of memory, which make it unusable for more complex problems.
However, as shown above, it is possible to achieve the same performance using **tf.data.Dataset** with only a few unrolled loops and a consequent improvement on the graph size.